# VSTO Word 2010 Add-in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, vsto

Currently I have programmed an Add-in which sets a value from a drop down menu to the Header of a document. It can either go in the Header or in the Footer however with both my code currently overwrites everything in that section. This is causing problems when Documents are sent in or a user tries to use a template. Any idea how I could make the code 'merge' with what is currently there either above or below?

Code Snippet:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    On Error GoTo err

    Dim classification As String
    Dim dc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document

    dc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument
    classification = "Classification: " & ComboBox1.Text

    With dc

        .ActiveWindow.View.SeekView = Word.WdSeekView.wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
        .ActiveWindow.Selection.HeaderFooter.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter
        .ActiveWindow.Selection.HeaderFooter.Range.Text = classification
        .ActiveWindow.View.SeekView = Word.WdSeekView.wdSeekMainDocument

    End With

    Me.Hide()

    Exit Sub
```

Just so you know the extra bit of code you can see is it searching that the classification does not currently exist and if so do not show form (set below).

Thanks,

Charles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured this out for anyone interested you can swap line....

ActiveWindow.Selection.HeaderFooter.Range.Text = classification

with the following one:

.ActiveWindow.Selection.HeaderFooter.Range.Text = .ActiveWindow.Selection.HeaderFooter.Range.Text + classification

However be warned it breaks the format of whatever is currently there...